# Reduce Noise on cycles engine and CPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, light

I have watched a lot of tutorials about how to reduce noise and rendering time and each one suggest some tips. In this scene http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35436, I remark that there are some noise points on the floor despite of it is flat surface and not very textured. In addition the hair of the person is very blurred. First, I fixed the samples as 100 and I have the image below. Second, I fix the samples as 200 but I still had noise in the floor. I try to modify other parameters (I have used ***limited global illumination*** as light paths and in the world scene and lamp i check the ***Multiple importance option***).

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is your hair material like?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise, I applied a texture image that gives by MakeHuman software

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18307/1853