# How do I reduce noise in renderings with Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am new to Blender with v. 2.80 and I wanted to ask how to reduce the "noise" in renderings with Cycles. It just doesn't want to render it correctly.

Comment: Hello. It seems this question already has a great answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18304/how-to-reduce-noise-in-cycles-render

Comment: If there was a way to do this for every single situation there would be no render settings, but just a render button in Blender. There is no one way to optimize every single case so you need to learn what to do in many different scenarios. There are quite a few of those possible(millions probably) so it cannot be answered fully with a single answer. Best thing to do would probably be to watch video tutorials about rendering online for the type of rendering you are after and then try to apply the knowledge to your specific situations. There is plenty of them on YouTube.